# Setting an ItemTemplate property in RunTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to display a small progress bar in a GridView within my ASP.Net application. I am trying to do it with an ItemTemplate.

```
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <table width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 75%; background-color: red"></td>
                                        <td style="width: 25%; background-color: green" ></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ItemTemplate>
```

I want to set the width percentage based on a calculation of some values within the row.

Can it be done somehow with Eval? Or do I need to do some code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following approach (sample calculation below):

```
<td style='<%# string.Format("width: {0}%; background-color: red", (int)Eval("Width") / 100) %>'></td>
```

But for readability sake you should better move this whole string construction into code behind and just call corresponding method on the page.

**Update.** As for code behind approach, here is how it can be done. Define a method that will do appropriate calculations and return the string:

```
protected string GetCellStyle(int width)
{
    return string.Format("width: {0}%; background-color: red", width / 100);
}
```

And call it with the same data binding syntax:

```
<td style='<%# GetCellStyle((int)Eval("Width")) %>'></td>
```

Comment: Thanks. Code behind might be better and easier to maintain/debug. What event would be used? OnRowBound?

Comment: @Craig, please see the update. You could also use `RowDataBound` event, but it seems to be an overhead here.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. This looks like a great approach. My only problem now is, I'm not 100% sure how to get the fields I need from the ObjectDataSource row that has been used to produce the row. There's two fields within my data row, used to create this row: IntitialProductiveHours and ProductiveHoursRemaining - and from that, I want to show a percentage of time remaining.

Comment: @Craig, any problem with just `Eval("IntitialProductiveHours")` and `Eval("ProductiveHoursRemaining")`? Make the function above to accept two parameters, perform the calculations and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! Works exactly as intended.